# Unpermitted parameter simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am trying to create a nested form with Simple_fields in ruby 4.

However, every time i try to enter data into the form I get a unpermitted parameter error in the server console after trying to submit.

I already tried the solutions found in the simple_form wiki and did some testing, but that doesn't seem to work.

The _form:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@enquiry) do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>

    <div class="form-inputs">
      <H1>Algemene informatie</H1>

      <%= f.input :reference, placeholder: 'Referentie' %>
      <br>

      <%= f.label :Locatie %>
      <%= f.select :location, [['Chemiepark', 'chemiepark'], ['Farmsum', 'farmsum'], ['Winschoten', 'winschoten']] %>

      <br>
      <%= f.input :description, placeholder: 'Omschrijving' %>
      <br>
      <%= f.input :date %>
      <br>
      <%= f.input :amount, placeholder: 'Aantal' %>

    </div>

    <hr>
    <% if false %>
        <div class="form-inputs">
          <%= f.simple_fields_for :enquiry_measures do |e| %>

              <H1>Maatregelen</H1>

              <%= e.input :responsible, placeholder: 'Verantwoordelijke' %>
              <br>
              <%# e.input :needed, as: :check_boxes,
                     collection: ["ja", "nee"] %>
          <% end %>
          <br>
        </div>
    <% end %>

    <div class="form-inputs">
      <%= f.simple_fields_for :tools do |t| %>
          <% @enquiry.tools.each do |tool| %>
              <%= field_set_tag 'Tool' do %>
                  <%= f.simple_fields_for "tool_attributes[]", tool do |tf| %>
                      <h1>Gereedschappen</h1>
                      <br>
                      <%= tf.input :handtool, placeholder: 'Handgereedschap' %>
                  <% end %>
              <% end %>
          <% end %>
      <% end %>

    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
      <%= f.button :submit %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

The strong attributes plus what i tested:

```
def enquiry_params
      # was gegenereerd door de scaffold params.fetch(:enquiry, {})
      params.require(:enquiry).permit(:reference, :location, :description, :date, :amount,
                                      :enquiry_measures_attributes => [:done, :responsible, :needed], :tools_attributes => [:handtool] )
                                      #:enquiry_measures_attributes => [:done, :responsible, :needed])
                                      #enquiry_measure_attributes: [:done, :responsible, :needed] )
```

**update**
code from models

```
class Enquiry < ActiveRecord::Base
  #ophalen van andere tabellen voor het formulier. Has_many is 1 op veel relatie
  #accepts_nested_attributes Nested attributes allow you to save attributes on associated records through the paren
  # de dere regel zorgt ervoor dat de maatregelen worden opgehaald via de tussentabel enquiry_measures.

  has_many :enquiry_measures, :class_name => 'EnquiryMeasure' #, inverse_of: :Enquiry
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :enquiry_measures, :allow_destroy => true

  has_many :measures, -> { uniq }, :class_name => 'Measure', :through => :enquiry_measures, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :measures, :allow_destroy => false

  has_many :controls, :class_name => 'Control' #, inverse_of: :Enquiry

  has_many :applicants, :class_name => 'Applicant' #, inverse_of: :Enquiry

  has_many :agrees, :class_name => 'Agree' #, inverse_of: :Enquiry

  has_many :signatures, :class_name => 'Signature' #, inverse_of: :Enquiry
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :signatures, :allow_destroy => false

  has_many :tools, :class_name => 'Tool', :dependent => :destroy  #, inverse_of: :Enquiry
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tools, :allow_destroy => true

  #:dependent => :destroy  zorgt ervoor dat de foreign record ook word verwijderd.

  #de instances van andere tabellen:

  e = Enquiry.new
  e.enquiry_measures.build(:enquiry_id => :id)
  e.measures.build


  # 28-11 MG de pagina's die in het form worden gebruikt.
  cattr_accessor :form_steps do
    %w(basic when measurements tool)
  end

  attr_accessor :form_step

  validates :reference, presence: true, if: -> { required_for_step?(:basic) }
  validates :amount, :date, presence: true, if: -> { required_for_step?(:when) }
  #validates :needed, presence: true, if: -> { required_for_step?(:measurements) }

  def required_for_step?(step)
    return true if form_step.nil?
    return true if self.form_steps.index(step.to_s) <= self.form_steps.index(form_step)
  end

  #voor het mailen met behulp van de mailgem:
  # Declare the e-mail headers. It accepts anything the mail method
  # in ActionMailer accepts.
  def headers
    {
        :subject => "My Contact Form",
        :to => "marco.groenhof@jpbgroep.nl",
        :from => %("#{name}" <#{email}>)
    }
  end

end
```

and 1 of the related models: in this case enquiry_measure

```
class EnquiryMeasure < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :enquiry
    validates_presence_of :enquiry
    has_many :measure
#serialize zodat de data uit de collection select met multiple: true op kan worden geslagen.
    serialize :measure

end
```

and tools:

```
class Tool < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :enquiry, :class_name => 'Enquiry' #, inverse_of: :applicant
  validates_presence_of :enquiry
end
```

I know class_name is not really needed anymore.

**UPDATE**

The logging:

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"i3YukMoOaYEuUdxk6kmhoQ5q9uLQHHISW+NAU/L+kNjSwMZERmdIIVXZvJUh0vTnEPidaMvMEIlVT/aTlkTNPw==", "enquiry"=>{"reference"=>"Test", "location"=>"chemiepark", "description"=>"3ro0qjhrojeofj", "date(1i)"=>"2017", "date(2i)"=>"1", "date(3i)"=>"3", "amount"=>"2", "tools_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"handtool"=>"Hamer"}}}, "commit"=>"Create Enquiry"}
```

The only weird thing i see is the "tools_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"handtool"=>"Hamer"}}}
Why is that 0 there? Could it be the id, because that would make sense to why i can not save.

And just to make sure, this is the tool tabel and foreign key:

```
 add_index "tools", ["enquiry_id"], name: "index_tools_on_enquiry_id", using: :btree

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name",            limit: 255
    t.string   "email",           limit: 255
    t.string   "password_digest", limit: 255
    t.datetime "created_at",                  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                  null: false
  end
  add_foreign_key "tools", "enquiries"
```

**UPDATE 4/01**
Just installed rails panel to see what that would say, but i keep thinking the problem is within the parameters:

```
{"reference":"test","location":"chemiepark","description":"iwopjf","date(1i)":"2017","date(2i)":"1","date(3i)":"4","amount":"2","tools_attributes":{"0":{"handtool":"hamer"}}}
```

Why does it keep sending that 0? i suspect it to be the tool id, which would declare the not being able to save.

Comment: You need to accept nested params from model as well

Comment: can you please post the code from model\

Comment: Models and logging have been added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to updatew this question as i got the answer that helped me. It may not be the completely correct answer, but i managed to solve my issue by using the default form_for in uby on Rails. A bit more coding work, but it does work.

Answer (score 0):

Try making you strong parameter as

```
params.require(:enquiry).permit(:reference, :location, :description, :date, :amount, enquiry_measures_attributes: [:id, :done, :responsible, :needed, :_destroy], tools_attributes: [:id, :handtool, :_destroy] )
```

And your model that is being nested should be something as below. Try doing this once.

```
class Tool < ActiveRecord::Base
  # For a while let's not have any validation.
end
```

Hope this will work in your case as I fix it for my own.

Comment: Hello, see the code. I already tried that, without succes. It doens't give any error in logging though, just rolls back inmediately

Comment: See the params thoroughly, there is some difference than yours and it works in my case of simple_form with nested values. Also accept nested params from model as well.

Comment: Hello, The models already have accept_nested_params in them, so that should be good. I also tried your code, but without succes. It still doesn't save, but with your code it also doesn't give a error, it just rolls back. The nested attributes should only be in the 'main' model, right?

Comment: After checking your parameters, and the updates you provided, there is some changes in the code. Instead of  tools_attributes: [:handtool], use tools_attributes: [:id, :handtool, :_destroy].  Also, there is no need of enquiry_measures_attributes: [:done, :responsible, :needed] that I have suggested earlier.

Comment: Hello, That is true, they are ot there because i was experimenting a lot, i put them behind #.

Comment: I still can't save the information unfortunatly. For the moment i am only using enquiry and as nested table: tool. Unfortunatly i am not getting a clear error about where it is going wrong.

Comment: It seems everything right on view level, and you have getting parameters in nice way. So issue is around saving the record. I found that you have used belongs_to :enquiry, :class_name => 'Enquiry' in Tool model. Try removing this for a while. And then test it. I have faced this issue in the past.

Comment: Hello, I just checked that, but i already removed the class_name part. removing that doesnt help the problem. Thats also what i found weird, i have done everything right, according to what i could find.

Comment: Hey I mean to say remove that  "belongs_to :enquiry" relation from your Tool model.

Comment: Ah right, then i get a Could not find the inverse association for tools (:enquiry in Tool) error. in the controller(because of the enquiry.tools.build) but doesnt removing that line also removes the relation?

Comment: anyway, when i remove that, i break all kind of things. I tried to work around that but haven't found the right solution yet.